# Query to find all the records where logoff time >6 PM for the past week

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I have a Database Table named `logoninfo`. Below is the schema.

```
       Record ID|User ID | Computer ID |LOGON_TIME|LOGOFF_TIME
```

The  Logon and logoff time are in milliseconds. All the users will logon daily and there will be multiple entries for same user and computer but different Record ID. I need to find all the records that logged off after 6 PM on the past week. To be more specific I need to know all the users who over stayed (logged off after 6 PM considered as Over stayed) and when they over stayed. Help me  with the query please. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: "*The Logon and logoff time are in milliseconds*" - milliseconds after what? After midnight? Unix Epoch? 1st of April? Why isn't that a `timestamp` or `time` column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is unix epoch. We cant use timestamp or time because of internal dependency. Is the above query is possible ?

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the dreaded epoch into a proper timestamp, then you can easily query that:

```
select *
from the_table
where 
  -- this selects every row where logged off is after 18:00 
  to_timestamp(logoff_time)::time >  time '18:00'
  -- the following two conditions select all rows from last week
  and to_timesamp(logoff_time) >= date_trunc('week', current_timestamp) - interval '1 week'
  and to_timesamp(logoff_time) < date_trunc('week', current_timestamp) - interval '1 week' + interval '1 week';
```